# Proving that a complex expression of probabilistic integrals is increasing in a given parameter

Tags: probability, distributions, integral

Let $f$ and $F$ denote the respective pdf and cdf of a probability
distribution on $\mathbb{R}$. Consider any natural $n\geq3$ and any real
$c$ such that $c\geq0$, and $\rho\geq0$.

We want to prove that:

$\frac{F(c)}{(n-1)(1-F(c))}\ln\left[  \frac{\left[  (n-1)(n-2)\int_{0}%
^{c}e^{\rho(b)}(1-F(b))F(b)^{n-3}f(b)db\right]  }{\left[  (n-1)(n-2)\int
_{0}^{c}e^{\rho(b)}F(b)^{n-3}\left[  F(c)-F(b)\right]f(b)  db\right]  }%
\frac{\left[  F(c)^{n-1}\right]  }{\left[  (n-1)F(c)^{n-2}-(n-2)F(c)^{n-1}%
\right]  }\right]  \\ \geq\ln\left[  \frac{\left[  (n-2)\int_{0}^{c}e^{\rho(b)}F(b)^{n-3}f(b)%
db\right]  }{\left[  (n-1)(n-2)\int_{0}^{c}e^{\rho(b)}(1-F(b))F(b)^{n-3}%
f(b)db\right]  }\frac{\left[  (n-1)F(c)^{n-2}-(n-2)F(c)^{n-1}\right]
}{[F(c)^{n-2}]}\right]$

These expressions are related to the expected values of order statistics, in particular the highest and second highest order statistics of n-1 entities. We know (by some exogenous theorem) that when $\rho=0$ the expressions (LHS and RHS) are identical. So it is sufficient to prove that the expression is increasing in $\rho$. Taking the derivative of the inequality with respect to $\rho$, we have:

$
\frac{\left(  \left[  \int_{0}^{c}be^{\rho b}(1-F(b))F(b)^{n-3}f(b)db\right]
\left[  \int_{0}^{c}e^{\rho b}f(b)F(b)^{n-3}\left[  F(c)-F(b)\right]
db\right]  -\left[  \int_{0}^{c}be^{\rho b}f(b)F(b)^{n-3}\left[
F(c)-F(b)\right]  db\right]  \left[  \int_{0}^{c}e^{\rho b}(1-F(b))F(b)^{n-3}%
f(b)db\right]  \right)  \left(  F(c)\right)  }{\left[  \int_{0}^{c}e^{\rho
b}f(b)F(b)^{n-3}\left[  F(c)-F(b)\right]  db\right]  (1-F(c))(n-1)}\geq
\frac{\left[  \int_{0}^{c}e^{\rho b}(1-F(b))F(b)^{n-3}f(b)db\right]  \left[
\int_{0}^{c}be^{\rho b}f(b)F(b)^{n-3}db\right]  -\left[  \int_{0}^{c}be^{\rho
b}(1-F(b))F(b)^{n-3}f(b)db\right]  \left[  \int_{0}^{c}e^{\rho b}%
f(b)F(b)^{n-3}db\right]  }{\int_{0}^{c}e^{\rho b}f(b)F(b)^{n-3}db}%
$

or, rearranging,

$\frac{\left(  F(c)\right)  }{(1-F(c))(n-1)}\geq\frac{\left[  \int_{0}%
^{c}e^{\rho b}f(b)F(b)^{n-3}\left[  F(c)-F(b)\right]  db\right]  }{\left[
\int_{0}^{c}e^{\rho b}f(b)F(b)^{n-3}db\right]  }\times  \frac{\left[
\int_{0}^{c}e^{\rho b}(1-F(b))F(b)^{n-3}f(b)db\right]  \left[  \int_{0}%
^{c}be^{\rho b}f(b)F(b)^{n-3}db\right]  -\left[  \int_{0}^{c}be^{\rho
b}(1-F(b))F(b)^{n-3}f(b)db\right]  \left[  \int_{0}^{c}e^{\rho b}%
f(b)F(b)^{n-3}db\right]  }{\left[  \int_{0}^{c}be^{\rho b}(1-F(b))F(b)^{n-3}%
f(b)db\right]  \left[  \int_{0}^{c}e^{\rho b}f(b)F(b)^{n-3}\left[
F(c)-F(b)\right]  db\right]  -\left[  \int_{0}^{c}be^{\rho b}f(b)F(b)^{n-3}%
\left[  F(c)-F(b)\right]  db\right]  \left[  \int_{0}^{c}e^{\rho
b}(1-F(b))F(b)^{n-3}f(b)db\right]  }$

Attempts to show that this inequality was true proved to be futile. Could someone suggest a strategy as to how one would go about this proof?

Comment: I haven't checked the algebra, but if you have taken the derivative with respect to two sides of an inequality, there is in general no reason to expect that the inequality still holds for the two first derivatives.

Comment: we just moved everything to the LHS and differentiated w.r.t. to $\rho$. So the inequality still holds because we know that at $\rho=0$ equality holds on both sides of the equation. What we are trying to do is to prove that the derivative is more than zero.

Comment: Are you just trying to prove a known result, or do you not actually know whether the result is true?

Comment: Simulations in mathematica/matlab show that the derivative is always positive, and that it is single peaked. The difference in the original expression is also increasing in rho.

Comment: These expressions appear to be related to expected values of functions of order statistics.  By not disclosing their origin, you make it difficult for readers to tap into any statistical insight that an understanding of order statistics might afford.  You would increase your chances of getting useful answers, then, by explaining the origins and motivation of this expression.

Comment: Which distributions did you perform simulation on, and why does that give you confidence that even if it applies to those distributions, it applies to all distributions (having a pdf)?

Comment: I performed simulations on uniform, exponential and normal distributions. I have confidence that it applies generally to other distributions as well, because the intuition that is garnered from other results that we have been able to prove apply to this inequality as well.

Comment: What is the exogenous theorem to which you refer?

Comment: The revenue equivalence theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revenue_equivalence)

Comment: Essentially $\rho$ is a risk parameter, so when $\rho=0$ the bidders are risk neutral and thus the revenue functions turn out to be the same